# React: Why focus event is remained after blurring outside webpage?

Tags: reactjs, input, focus

**Problem**

When I focus input element and blur at outside webpage like Chrome dev tool, focus event is remained in that page. So, when I click other element except input, focus event is occurred at input element.

**Reproduction**

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/why-focus-event-is-occurred-when-blur-at-chrom-devtools-z2rzv?file=/src/App.js

You can test through following steps.

1. Open chrome dev tool and select `console tab`
2. Focus input element → `focus` is logged
3. Blur by clicking dev tool part → `blur` is logged
4. **Click white background (not input element) → `focus` and `blur` is logged**

I cannot understand **why step 4 is occurred.** I searched lots of website including official react docs and SO, I couldn't find. What is the reason?